# all positive integers satisfying the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find all positive integers $n>1$ such that the following series is divisible by $n$:
>   $$1^n + 2^n + 3^n + \ldots + (n-1)^n.$$

I started with considering separate cases for even and odd values of $n$ but couldn't make any progress, and on searching I found following conjecture:

> If $n$ is a prime, then
>   $$n \mid 1^{n-1}+2^{n-1} + \ldots + (n-1)^{n-1} + 1,$$

but I am not able to understand the proof.
It seems the above is by fermat

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $n$ is odd. Consider the sum modulo $n$. Then
$$(n - k)^n \equiv (-k)^n \equiv (-1)^n k^n \equiv -k^n.$$
So, each term of the sum pairs uniquely with another term of the sum which is its negative. So, when $n$ is odd, the sum should be $0$ modulo $n$, i.e. divisible by $n$.

Otherwise, consider the case where $n$ is even. Then $n = 2^km$ for some odd $m$, and positive integer $k$. Consider the sum modulo $2^k$. Note that $k \le n$, hence if $r$ is an even number between $1$ and $n - 1$, then $2^k \mid r^n$.

Otherwise, if $r$ is an odd number in the range $1$ to $n - 1$. Then $r^n$ is odd, and there are an odd number of such terms. So, adding all the terms modulo $2^k$, we obtain an odd number, implying that the sum cannot be $0$ modulo $2^k$, and hence it can't be $0$ modulo $n$.

Therefore, the sum is divisible by $n$ if and only if $n$ is odd.